# Separating each grep found record by delimiter

Tags: grep

Team,

I have few exceptions thrown to a log file.  Iam using the following regular expression to derive all the exceptions and errors from the log.

Now, i wanted to collect each exception stack trace message, few lines before say 10 lines, 10 lines after. I was able to do this by adding -A 10 -B 10, "but" i want each such exception log record( 10 lines before , exception trace, 10 lines after ) to get separated by say "\n" or some thing as delimiter between them, so that i can collect each of these blocks separately and display in ui. Any help?

grep "ERROR\|FATAL\|Exception\|at.*.java\:.*" my.log.

Thanks in Advance!
Santhosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can do it all in `awk`:

```
awk '{r[FNR]=$0} /pattern/{w[++i]=FNR} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){for(k=w[j]-10;k<=w[j]+10;k++)if(k>0 && k<=FNR)print r[k];printf "\n"}}' logfile
```

**IMPORTANT**: You need to remove the word `pattern` and put your search string in place of it.

The code in the first pair of curly braces (`{}`) saves each line of your input file in array r[1], r[2], r[3] etc. Think of `r[]` as the `RECORDS` of your file.

The code in the next pair of curly braces is only activated on lines that match your search pattern, and in there I remember the line number of the matching lines in array w[1], w[2] etc. Think of `w[]` as the lines you `WANT`.

The code in the last set of curly braces is activated at the end of yur input file... it goes through the `w[]` array of lines that you want and then starts another loop 10 lines before until 10 lines after the line you wanted printing out those lines and then following them with that all-important blank line you wanted.

Comment: Mark,  I was using the pattern(^[\tException]) to retrieve stack traces, but what i want is to retrieve 10 lines before the stack trace, stack trace , 10 lines after the stack trace as a single record, then display each of these records( this i will take care), currently it prints stack trace================== awk '{r[FNR]=$0} /^[\tException]/{w[++i]=FNR} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){for(k=w[j]-10;k<=w[j]+10;k++)if(k>0 && k<=FNR)print r[k];printf "\n"}}' my.log

Comment: I can't tell what is going on very easily from that. Please try using a very minimal `awk` command like the one that follows so that we can get something that works and then build on it till it does what you want... `awk '/Exception/{print}' my.log`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
N=10
pattern=xyz
matchinglines=($(awk -v p="$pattern" '$0~p{print NR}' logfile))    # Generate array of matching line numbers
for x in ${matchinglines[@]}
do
   ((start=x-N))
   [[ $start -lt 1 ]] && start=1   # Avoid passing negative line numbers to sed
   ((end=x+N))
   sed -ne "${start},${end}p" logfile
   echo
done
```